# Aes algorithm token Decryption using Crypto Js key getting issue format Exception : Invalid Character (at character 1085) in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, aes, cryptojs, pointycastle

Here below is my token decryption code with cryptoJsKey,
here encryptedText is token & password is CryptoJsKey,

```
 static String decryptAES(String encryptedText, String password) {
    final keyBytes = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(password));
    final iv = Uint8List(16);
    final cipher = BlockCipher("AES/CBC")..init(false, ParametersWithIV(KeyParameter(keyBytes), iv));

    final encryptedBytes = base64.decode(encryptedText);
    final decryptedBytes = decryptBytes(cipher, encryptedBytes);

    final decryptedText = utf8.decode(decryptedBytes);
    return decryptedText;
  }
```

Here i am successfully decoded token but after token decode i am getting
another cipher Text like this
eyJJc1N1cGVydmlzb3IiOiJGYWxzZSIsIklzQWdlbnQiOiJGYWxzZSIsyc29XJOYW1lIjoiSml0aGl***********

for this token iam using a method for conversion

```
static String decodeJWT(String jwt) {
    final parts = jwt.split('.');
    if (parts.length != 3) {
      return 'Invalid JWT format';
    }
    final encodedPayload = parts[1];
    final missingPadding = 4 - (encodedPayload.length % 4);
    final paddedPayload = (missingPadding > 0) ? encodedPayload + '=' * missingPadding : encodedPayload;
    final decodedPayload = String.fromCharCodes(base64Url.decode(paddedPayload));
    print("payload $decodedPayload");
    return decodedPayload;
  }
```

in this conversion i am getting issue under this line
final decodedPayload = String.fromCharCodes(base64Url.decode(paddedPayload));
The error message is like
FormatException: Invalid character (at character 1085)
...CIsIm5iZiI6MTY5OTY1NDUxOSwiZXhwIjoxNzAwMDAwMTE5LCJpYXQiOjE2OTk2NTQ1MTl9====

Comment: Something is wrong with the padding as you need to pad up to a multiple of 4 characters (i.e. zero, one or two padding characters, three is not possible and 4 is not necessary; 5 is right out), but I'm wondering why you are padding base64url as that scheme doesn't even use padding characters.

Comment: Note that you cannot summon persons unless they have commented above, and it is considered bad form to ask specific people for help here. Comments are mainly for clarifying posts and giving hints / help such as this.

Comment: So just removing the padding part and if the base64url encoding is correctly implemented it should work.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes so which line of code i need to remove can you specify with examples'

Comment: @Nns_ninteyFIve just so you're aware, you're exposing some information in that base64 string that might not supposed to be shared on the open internet. It might be worth editing it out of the question and using a sample payload with no personally identifiable information instead.

Comment: @its not a proper token.

Comment: @ rmtmckenzie i  am just a newbie  to this , i got this aes decryption  code from a medium document and  i don't know the method decodeJWT is unneccessary or not , i got this method from chatGpT for decrypted cipher text to plain text.

Comment: `decodeJWT()` has a bug when determining the padding size, correct is `final missingPadding = (4 - encodedPayload.length) % 4`, s. [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=2724039d16e178f296d6b904c7768719). Alternatively, you can use `normalize()` (as suggested in the answer).

Comment: Regarding padding for Base64url: Both, with or without padding, are compliant with RFC 4648 (see [3.2 Padding of Encoded Data](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-3.2)). I.e. whether a library uses padding or not must be checked in the documentation of that library.

Comment: @Topaco can we have any other alternative options or is it ok to proceed.

Comment: From a purely technical point of view, decryption and decoding (when using the fix) seem to work. Whether you are on the right track, I cannot say, since you do not provide any context and no test data for a repro.

Comment: @Topaco  yeah i am talking about this comment "Regarding padding for Base64url: Both, with or without padding, are compliant with RFC 4648 (see 3.2 Padding of Encoded Data). I.e. whether a library uses padding or not must be checked in the documentation of that library. " i did n't understand the correct point

Comment: In your example, padding is used once for Base64url (dart, `base64url.decode()`) and once not (signed JWT/JWS). Here it could be assumed that there is an inconsistency or even a bug in one of the two implementations. But this is not the case! Padding is optional according to the specification (RFC 4648), so both implementations are compliant with the specification. I just wanted to point this out again with my previous comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255918/discussion-between-nns-ninteyfive-and-topaco).

Answer (score 2):

There is some sort of issue with your algorithm. Base64 encoding should never have more than 2 characters of padding. You could go look at the spec or a reference example of code to pad the input, but dart actually provides an easier way to do it with the `base64Url.normalize` function.

This is how you can use it:

```dart
Uint8List base64UrlDecode(String inputBase64) {
  final normalized = base64Url.normalize(inputBase64);
  return base64Url.decode(normalized);
}
```

If you are still getting errors, that probably means that the encoding of the data is being done incorrectly, or you have an off-by-1 error somewhere.

---

As an aside, your code looks to have a fairly serious security vulnerability unless you're doing something outside of the decryptAES function. AES/CBC should only ever be used in addition to a MAC or hash, as otherwise it is vulnerable to bit-flipping attacks. You could probably argue this is mitigated by using a signed JWT and you might be correct, but best practice in JWE is to authenticate the entire package whether it's through the encryption algorithm or by adding a mac. If you have control of the server software, a simple(ish) fix would be to switch to AES/GCM. However, unless you are a security expert and this is just some very unfinished code, I think the adage that you shouldn't ever write your own cryptography code probably applies here. I'd recommend looking into using a library such as [jose](https://pub.dev/packages/jose), although if your code is being used somewhere with strict security constraints you should probably have it and any libraries reviewed by a professional.

I also seriously hope that you're not using a plaintext password as the encryption key as it appears from the function. Passwords are horribly insecure as encryption keys and should always be hashed using a secure password algorithm first - not just a simple SHA, but rather something like argon2, PBKDF2, scrypt or bcrypt. If you're using a password directly, unless you can guarantee the password is always going to be 128 bits of very random data, it basically makes the encryption worthless.

Comment: i  am just a newbie  to this , i got this aes decryption  code from a medium document and  i don't know the method decodeJWT is unneccessary or not , i got this method from chatGpT for decrypted cipher text to plain text.

Comment: Ah. Well unfortunately the best advice I can give you is to avoid doing anything with encryption unless you have a _very_ solid understanding of it - it's one of the parts of software development where the "move fast and break things" philosophy should never apply. If you don't know what you're doing, it's very easy to leave open security vulnerabilities that basically make using the encryption useless in the first place, and you won't find out about them until too late.

Comment: Using well-supported libraries rather than rolling your own code is a step in the right direction, but even those have pitfalls so you should read the documentation of the library and the JWE spec very thoroughly before continuing, as well as look into some background information on cryptography. Honestly unless you're doing something very specialize, you should probably just be ensuring you use HTTPS between the server & client as a lot of work has been done into making that secure; adding your own level of encryption below it unnecessary in most cases unless you need to store it encrypted.